# Do I need need any special certificates of permission from android to publish android apps ?How to sign android applications in release mode?

Tags: android

When I have tried to publish a android App for Nokia X in the Nokia store

I am seeing the following Error while validation at publish.nokia.com

The package name extracted from an APK file does not match the package name specified in the content item.

The APK file contains an invalid certificate. It is either CN (common name) = Android Debug or the certificate expires before Oct 22, 2033.

Do I need need any special certificates of permission from android to publish android apps ?

I have been to

Signing in Release Mode

in the page below

http://developer.android.com/tools/p...l#ExportWizard

```
C:\>$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
'-alias' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Please help me publish my android app in release mode

Comment: You can also use Eclipse to generate a certificate for your application.

Comment: can u be brief on method or procedure on eclipse. Thanks

Comment: Ok I got it Iam following To create a signed and aligned APK in Eclipse:

Select the project in the Package Explorer and select File > Export.
Open the Android folder, select Export Android Application, and click Next.
The Export Android Application wizard now starts, which will guide you through the process of signing your application.

Comment: Yes that's it. try it.

Comment: I have to select Use Existing key store or Crete new key store selection in Key Store selection window ? Location? pw? confirm ?

Comment: You can create new if you want, else you can use the same which you created at command line just before this.

Comment: what about the path Can I give any path?

Comment: path : if you are creating new then give the path where you want to store your certificate file. If you have already created then give it's path in that text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried to execute you wrong command syntax for keytool. You should use following syntax,

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keysore -alias Android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Once you execute above line at command prompt then it will ask you for password. That means you are on correct way. You need to provide password & confirm password and then your certificate will get generated.

The another way to create certificate is using Eclipse, See steps,

- Right click on the Project from Project Explorer in eclipse
- Select Android Tools Option
- Select Export Signed Application Package

  [image]
- This will load a new dialog box, using which you can either use existing certificate or you can create new one.

  [image]
- To create a new certificate , select new, give path & file name, password & confirm password.

  [image]
- Click on next will display following dialog, Here you can fill the appropriate information.

  [image]
- Clicking next will ask path where you want to store your singed .apk. Give proper path and click on "Finish"
- Your application is ready for Google Play Market.

Comment: Now Iam able to generate RSA Keypair like      C:\>keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keysore -alias Android -keyalg RSA -key
size 2048 -validity 10000                                         Is CN=SKumar, OU=Individual, O=Ind, L=Hyd, ST=AP, C=IN correct?
  [no]:  yes  Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA1withRSA) with
 a validity of 10,000 days
        for: CN=SKumar, OU=Individual, O=Ind, L=Hyd, ST=AP, C=IN
Enter key password for <Android>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
Re-enter new password:
[Storing release.keysore .Now what's next ?

Comment: How to sign the application. Where  will be keypair generated. when and where it will ask them.

Comment: Go to your documents and settings folder, open your user's folder and it is there with the name you given.

Comment: The certificate file create at the same location where you use in command prompt.

Comment: C:\>keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keysore -alias Android -keyalg RSA -key
size 2048 -validity 10000 Here what is my path  ?

Comment: Ok, so your release.keystore is at c:\> , Open your C: drive from my computer and you can see it there.

Comment: with what name and excatly in C drive ?

Comment: when  I try in eclipse to search for keystore  I found Skumar.csr in C drive but with date 4th but when I give keystore passowrd and say  Next. It says "Invalid key store format."

Comment: I will have lunch and come Thanks

Comment: @user3382121, is your application signed properly now ?

Comment: yes it seesm so as the .apk got created now  and while publishing in the nokia  store no Errors or warnings shown

Comment: @user3382121 Thats good. You may accept my answer by ticking a green tick mark besides my answer.

Comment: Yes Thanks for your support be with me Iam opening n= a new query about   installing app to device using android eclipse

Comment: @user3382121, You welcome. Sure you may post other question you have.

Comment: Can I port this app to BlackBerry now ?

Comment: @user3382121 Nopes, because android uses .apk while blackberry uses .cod I dont think you can port it directly to BB.

Comment: No I mean thru porting procedure only  which I know

Comment: @user3382121 I have no idea about it. Sorry

Comment: Ok thank you  I will ask my query if any in the next question .thanks

Comment: @Kedarnath, great explanation, +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need a special cert, the keytool generates a certificate.  The correct command is keytool -alias, not just -alias.

Comment: Can you be more brief as I want to publish my android app today and Iam new to it. How to get it from CA also?

Comment: Now Iam able to generate RSA Keypair like

Comment: How to check if my application is properly signed after following all the procedure above  i.e after Clicking next will ask path where you want to store your singed .apk. Give proper path and click on "Finish"

Comment: If application is properly signed then only it will generate .apk file else it will stop with error dialog.

Comment: After  the final step i.e Key Creation  Iam seeing the following =warning    Certificate expires in 50 years.
WARNING: destination file already exists

Comment: @user3382121 that means you have previously created one successful signed application. If you want to override click "ok" else choose different path to store. '50 years' is fine.